# How to find the average of randomly generated numbers in JAVA

Tags: java, random, average

I am randomly generating a GPA for a student in the class. In the app I repeat the step 8 times, for a total of 8 different GPA's. At the end of my print statement I want to calculate the total of all 8 GPA's. I only want it to print out once. Where should I put the steps for finding the average, in the class or in the app?

In the code I have multiple areas where I tried to find the average, but it did not print out correctly. I just made them into notes.

(this is in the public static void)

```
for(int i = 1; i < 9; i++ )
 {
     //System.out.println(sd.getInfo());
     System.out.println("Semester " + i + " - " + sd.semesterGPA());
     System.out.println();
 }
   System.out.println(sd.averageGPA());
 }
```

(this is in the public class student)

```
   String semesterGPA()
     {
       for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
     {         
          gpa = Math.random();
          myRandomNumber = (gpa * 4.1 );
          //String strDouble = String.format("%.2f", myRandomNumber);
          //average = (i/8);
          //System.out.println(firstName + "'s average GPA is " + average);
      }

    return firstName + "'s GPA is " +  String.format("%.2f", myRandomNumber);
    //System.out.println(firstName + "'s average GPA is " + average);
  }

String averageGPA()
{
   // double gpa = sum / count;

    return firstName + "'s average GPA is ";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a static variable to keep track of all the GPAs (inside the Student class) and then finally return it.

```
class Student{

  static double total;

  String semesterGPA(){
    .
    .
         //just add the GPA to the total before return statement
    total += myRandomNumber;
         //return statement 
  }

  String averageGPA()
  {
    double averageGPA = total / 9;
         //return statement including averageGPA
  }
}
```

Comment: Why the return type is String ?

Comment: In the question mentioned, he used the return type of the functions as String. Thats why

Answer (score 0):

I tried with Java-8

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics statistic = IntStream.range(0, 8)
    .boxed() //int to Integer
    .collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(i -> Math.random() * 4.1)); //collect to statistic

System.out.println(statistic.getAverage());
```

You will get the average from 8 results from `Math.random()*4.1`

Answer (score 0):

assume your have a GPA list,find the average value your can use the follow doce in java 8

```
    List<Double> gpas = Arrays.asList(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0);
    double average = gpas.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(value -> value.doubleValue()));
    System.out.println(average);
```